# Missing output in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, netbeans, output

I tested the following class:

```
public class PrintLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("print line!");

    }

}
```

**Netbeans says:**

```
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**In Eclipse** `I read >> print line! <<`

What can I do?

Comment: No, in Netbeans you will get :`run:
print line!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans might be set to open a different window for the *Output*. What you are looking at is the compiler output. Maybe you just said *build*  or *clean and build*. You need to press the button with the little *play* symbol that says *run*  or you can use the key: *F6*.

If the *output* window doesn't open automatically, go to the menu *window* -> *output* -> *output*  (or use the keys *ctrl* + *4*)